# How to get/store related data from documents MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the two collections:

1. prototypes
2. fields

Each prototype can contains some `fields`. So structure document in **collection fields** is:

```
{ _id: "940jei34wrewrwr1", name: "Opa" },
{ _id: "940jei34wrewrwr2", name: "Opa1" },
{ _id: "940jei34wrewrwr3", name: "Opa2" }
```

And **collection prototype** is:

```
{ _id: "1", name: "PA", fields: { ... }},
{ _id: "2", name: "BA", fields: { ... }},
{ _id: "3", name: "CA", fields: { ... }}
```

So, in **collection prototype** I need to store fields in `fields` key.

But I am not sure, it must be array: fields: `[ ... ]` of id elements of fields, or object: `fields: { ... }` with full data of field like this:

```
,fields: {{ _id: "940jei34wrewrwr1", name: "Opa" }, { _id: "940jei34wrewrwr2", name: "Opa1" }}
```

What is the best way to store this related data?

In which case it will be easy to extract and update data?

Thanks!

Comment: you must store the array of objects as in the question you stated the example data it should look like this ,**fields: [{ _id: "940jei34wrewrwr1", name: "Opa" }, { _id: "940jei34wrewrwr2", name: "Opa1" }]** basically object of objects doesn't make sense but array of objects does. You can use aggregate , populate and many more functionalities that mongo provide by using array of objects.

Comment: Okay I get all fields from collection using $in operator, Then I try to save it into `fields`.

Comment: Can you share one sample in PHP?